# slideToggle remove other active classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple menu/accordion slider. I want to add the class="active" to the clicked  link and slide down to show the UL. When another separate menu item is clicked then the active class should be removed from the previous element and added to the one just clicked. Also if the same  is clicked when in active mode then the slider should slide up and remove the active class.

I've tried various configurations of the below but each time have problems getting the active class to be removed if the same  is clicked to slide up. Any help is appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(menuSlide) {
    $('li.menu-item-has-children a').click(function () {        
        if ($('li.menu-item-has-children a').hasClass('active')) {
            $('li.menu-item-has-children a').removeClass('active');
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }

        $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
        $(this).parent().siblings().children().next().slideUp();

        return false;
    });
});
```

Update - have created a quick [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pon79tjo/8/) that demonstrates the problem, apologies for not doing on opening question. You can see that if same item is clicked to toggle the state remains active.

Comment: Can we also see the relevant HTML? Helps to know the structure of the elements being worked with.

Comment: Remove the `else` from your condition. If your anchor tag has active in the class it will not set the new class. Basically you're saying: If any anchors have the class name active, remove it. If non of the anchor tags have the class name active, set one.

Comment: It would be  a lot easier if there was some HTML to go with your JavaScript. Maybe you could create a running example in [js-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that illustrates your problem?

Comment: Apologies have updated with Fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to support toggling, you should not remove active class from current element so

```js
$(document).ready(function(menuSlide) {
  var $as = $('li.menu-item-has-children a').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul').slideToggle();
    $(this).parent().siblings().children('ul').slideUp();
    $(this).parent().siblings().children('.active').removeClass('active');
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.menu-item-has-children ul {
  display: none;
}
a.active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="menu-item-has-children">
    <a>1</a>
    <ul>
      <li>1.1</li>
      <li>1.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item-has-children">
    <a>1</a>
    <ul>
      <li>1.1</li>
      <li>1.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item-has-children">
    <a>1</a>
    <ul>
      <li>1.1</li>
      <li>1.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think the OP's mistake is with the else condition. This is a good solution but doesn't explain the reason for the issue in hand.

Comment: This works perfectly for me but I'd still like to understand where I was going wrong in my original code. Thank you Arun.

Comment: @d1ch0t0my `$('li.menu-item-has-children a').hasClass('active')` will return true if any of the `a` element has the class active... so assume you clicked on second item then is moving to first item... now the if statement will return true since the second item has the class.. so not the first item will not get the active class

Answer (score 0):

We simply store the previous click div in a variable and then slide up that div on click :

```
var previousElement = 0;
$(document).ready(function(menuSlide) {
    $('li.menu-item-has-children a').click(function () {

    if ($('li.menu-item-has-children a').hasClass('active')) {
        $('li.menu-item-has-children a').removeClass('active');
        previousElement = 0;
    }else {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        if(previousElement != 0) {
             $(previousElement).removeClass('active');
             $(previousElement).slideUp();
        }
        previousElement =  this;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is,

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('li.menu-item-has-children .content').slideUp();
       $(document).on('click','li.menu-item-has-children a',function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         $this = $(this);
         $('li.menu-item-has-children a').removeClass('active');
         $this.addClass('active');
         $('li.menu-item-has-children a').parent().find('.content').slideUp();
         $this.parent().find('.content').slideDown();
       });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
 <ul>
  <li class="menu-item-has-children">
   <a href="#">A</a>
   <div class="content">
    AAAA AAAA AAAA
   </div>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item-has-children">
   <a href="#">B</a>
   <div class="content">
    BBBB BBBB BBBB
   </div>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item-has-children">
   <a href="#">C</a>
   <div class="content">
    CCCC CCCC CCCC
   </div>
  </li>
 </ul>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In below example, i've worked same link click twice, please let me know if you are requesting this thing or not,

```
$(document).ready(function(menuSlide) {
    $('li.menu-item-has-children a').click(function () {  
        console.log($(this).hasClass('active'));
        if($(this).hasClass('active') == false)
        {
        if ($('li.menu-item-has-children a').hasClass('active')) {
            $('li.menu-item-has-children a').removeClass('active');
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }

        $(this).next('ul').slideDown();
        $(this).parent().siblings().children().next().slideUp();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```